# chrome.storage.local not working, sometimes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm creating a chrome extension and this is the first time I'm working with JS or async for that matter.

The BG script gets a JSON and saves all the data into local storage when chrome / extension is initialized. Once the user navigates to a specific page, the content script kicks in and checks specific ids from the page against the local storage. If it finds the id it creates an element with an icon next to it.

It works fine. However, from time to time when I reload the page, nothing is being get from the local storage, even when I want to log everything from there, nothing is being logged. Like the storage is empty.

Might have something to do with async? The strange thing is that the most inner part of the code still logs the fact that the id cannot be found in the storage so nothing is skipped.

My content script looks like this:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;

loopThatList();

function loopThatList() {
    var logoElements = document.querySelectorAll('.class > a:not(.class)');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({removeRatedValueObj: "get"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.removeRatedValueObj);
        chrome.storage.local.get(function(result){console.log(result)});
        logoElements.forEach(function(item, i) {
            var href = item.href;
            var regex = /(?:https:\/\/www\.site\.com\/stuff\/|-[^$]+)/gm;
            var id = href.replace(regex, '');
            storage.get(id, function(result){
                var hasRating = item.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.rating > span');
                if (typeof(hasRating) !== "undefined" && hasRating !== null && response.removeRatedValueObj === "true") {
                    item.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
                }
                else {
                    if(!isEmpty(result)) {
                        //stuff;
                    }
                    else if (isEmpty(result)) {
                        console.log("Cannot find id in storage");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The data is being saved to local storage in the BG script, which from what I read happens when you launch chrome or turn the extension on. (I have logging set up which supports that) So the data is physically in there LONG before the content script wants to access local storage. Or am I missing something?

As for the lucky conincidence, I can refresh the page 100 times and 100/100 the data will load. This happens ONLY when the tab is not being used for some time.

Comment: Without seeing the real code in the background script all I had was "The BG script gets a JSON and saves all the data into local storage" so I assumed this happens in onMessage listener. But with the new info, it sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: I will edit the main post, sorry about that. What would you say the correct action is now? Where does one report it so that it doesn't fizzle out? I saw a chromium forum of some kind some time back. EDIT: found this page https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entryafterlogin

Comment: You can try verifying your idea by manually freezing/discarding a tab in `chrome://discards` and the bug reporting site short URL is https://crbug.com.

Comment: Will try and report back. Thank you for that, didn't know about `chrome://discards`.

Comment: Nope, freezing or discarding has nothing to with it. If I discard, then go back to tab, it automatically reloads with all the local storage data, if I freeze and reload, works as well. I don't get it...

EDIT: now I tried and despite the tab being active, I reloaded and local storage didn't load. So there must really be an issue with the async stuff. But where?

Comment: @wOxxOm I think I figured it out. The documentation says `A background page is loaded when it is needed, and unloaded when it goes idle. ... Background scripts unload on their own after a few seconds of inactivity.`. At this point, since I didn't know about this, my BG script flushes local storage and loads the data anew. So what has been happening is that when I wasn't using the tab/page, the BG page unloaded, I refreshed, (and I'm guessing) both the BG and content scripts ran at the same time, the data got flushed from local storage and hence the content script couldn't find it...

Comment: We would have spotted that immediately if the background script code and manifest.json were present in the question. Extensions have many moving parts so it's important to post all related code and info.

Comment: Will keep that in mind for future questions. Thanks for your time